# Beer-Quiche Game - Hybrid Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

Can a hybrid equilibrium for the following game be found?

Cho and Kreps (1987) introduced what is now a famous two player signaling game. First, Nature selects player 1, who knows his type, to be either a wimp (W), with probability p = 0.1, or surly (S), with probability 1− p = 0.9. Player 1 then chooses what to have for breakfast: beer (B) or
quiche (Q). A surly type prefers beer while a wimp prefers quiche. Player 1’s preferred breakfast gives him a payoff of 1 while his less-preferred choice gives him 0. After breakfast player 2 observes what player 1 ate but does not know whether he is a wimp or surly. Player 2 then chooses whether to duel (D) with player 1 or not to duel (N). Player 1, regardless of his type, prefers
no duel, yielding him an extra payoff of 2, to a duel, which gives him 0. (For example, if player 1 eats his preferred breakfast and avoids a duel then his final payoff is 3, while if he eats his preferred breakfast and is forced into a duel then his final payoff is 1.) Player 2, however, prefers to duel if and only if player 1 is a wimp. If player 1 is surly then player 2’s payoff is 0 from D and 1 from N. If player 1 is a wimp then player 2’s payoff is 2 from D and 1 from N.

Comment: Is this your homework? (I have seen exactly the same text as in the second paragraph posted on another website.)

Comment: No, it wasn't. I was practicing to make my understanding of the concept stronger. For the given question, we need not find the hybrid equilibrium. It will never have a separating equilibrium but pooling will exist.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you wanted to write in the final paragraph. 1. What do you mean "*we need not find the hybrid equilibrium*", and if we do not need it, why do you want to find it? 2. In this final paragraph you write "*There will exist a pooling equilibrium*" but in your first you write "*there are no pooling nor separating perfect Bayesian equilibrium for the given game*". Which is it? 3. Could you maybe edit your question and type in your deductions and your calculations in Mathjax? It would make it easier to follow, and also make a potential answer easier.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the edit! Could you maybe edit your question again and type in your deductions and your calculations in Mathjax?